# Turning PC Into A Server

Tags: server, hosting, self-hosting

Sorry if I have this in the wrong community but I'm hoping one of you can help me out anyway.

I have a web hosting account with a UK company who I'm happy with, but I'd like to set up a little hosting account from my laptop, just to see if it's possible and easy enough to do really.

Trouble is I've been doing a lot of research online but coming up empty whenit comes to more of a "complete guide".  Do any of you know of a good resource for setting up a home server for publishing "Live" websites with custom TLD domain names?  I have a localhost server running and files hosted on there but I'm really looking for help with the IP and DNS parts for the custom domains.

For reference, I have a machine running Win7, Appserv 2.5.10, UK broadband and a .co.uk domain name registered with 123-reg.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to:

- Point your domain to your laptop.
- If you get static public IP address from your ISP, then you can just point the A record to this IP address.
- **Where do I set this A record?** Almost all domain registrars give you a nameserver for free. You point your domain to their nameservers (generally ns1.somedomain.com and ns2.samedomain.com etc.). In the nameserver config, create a A (stands for authoritative) record and put in your static IP address.
- **What if my ISP doesn't give me an static IP address?** This is where services like [dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/) come into picture. They give you an agent that you'll install on your laptop, it detects the change in IP address and automatically updates the Nameservers accordingly. There are some free variants of dyndns as well if you don't want to spend money on this.
- **But my laptops IP address is something like 192.168.x.x and my site runs on localhost (127.0.0.1)?** Your laptop is most likely NATed. Think about your public IP address to be that of your router. You will need to forward any connection coming to your router on port 80 or 443 to your laptop's (192.168.x.x) corresponding ports. This is called Port-Forwarding and all routers support this. Port-Forwarding is done by logging on to the admin interface of your router (Many times its at http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1).
- **But again my application is accessible at localhost?** You need to make sure your apache/nginx listens on 0.0.0.0 or atleast 192.168.x.x interface. This is how computers outside your laptop will be able to make connection to your laptop on port 80/443.